# How do I change the properties of a Character-set-server in Amazon LightSales?

Tags: mysql

I'm using version 5.7 of Amazon LightSale mysql.
I'd like to change the character-set-server property, but I don't know how. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change server system variables when connected with a MySQL client with the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html) statement. See the example with the `mysql` console command, which changes the [`character_set_server`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_server) setting:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'character_set_server';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| character_set_server | utf8  |
+----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET character_set_server=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'character_set_server';
+----------------------+--------+
| Variable_name        | Value  |
+----------------------+--------+
| character_set_server | latin1 |
+----------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```